# EntityFrameworkCore using wrong column in query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to write my first web api with .net core.  I am using VS2017 and core 1.1.  I've got everything working except for one of my objects (I've tried it with that last line commented and uncommented...it makes no difference):

```
public class Tag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool ShowInFilter { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SubscriberTag> SubscriberTags { get; set; }
}
```

My repository code looks like this:

```
private SubscriptionContext db;
public TagRepository(SubscriptionContext context) { db = context; }
public Tag Find(int key) => db.Tags.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ID == key);
```

That is being called from my TagController:

```
private iTagRepository TagItems { get; set; }
public TagController(iTagRepository tagItems) {TagItems = tagItems; }

[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTag")]
public IActionResult Get(int id) { return new ObjectResult( TagItems.Find(id) ); }
```

The problem is when I run it, the query that is executed is:

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'SELECT TOP(2) [a].[ID], [a].[Name], 
    [a].[ShowInFilter], [a].[SubscriberID]
FROM [Tags] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[ID] = @__key_0',N'@__key_0 int',@__key_0=1
```

which throw and error because Tags doesn't contain a column called SubscriberID.
I've searched all my code and SubscriberID only shows up two places (in other classes which are not being used here).  I have no partial classes in my entire project (saw that was an issue on a related question.)

Why is EF adding this column to its query and how do I fix it?

As requested here is the class that contains subscriberID:

```
public class SubscriberTag
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long subscriberID { get; set; }
    public int tagID { get; set; }

    public Subscriber Subscriber { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Subscriber class (lots of irrelevant properties removed):

```
public class Subscriber
{
    public Subscriber()
    {
        //a few value initalizers/defaults
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    //.......

    public ICollection<Subscribers.Models.Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subscribers.Models.Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but I would look at the migrations that created the database.  Looks like EF could not determine which class was the principal in the Tag-Subscription relationship and added the SubscriberID as a foreign key to Tag for you.  Can we see the SubscriberID  is the primary key of?

Comment: Do you have another entity class that inherits `Tag`? In other words, what happens if you change the definition to `public sealed class Tag`?

Comment: @IvanStoev No... adding sealed to the definition has no effect.

Comment: @DanielBoyer Can we see the `Subscriber` class as well? If `Subscriber` has a property: `public List<Tag> Tags {get;set;}` that would explain EF's foreign key expectation... but not why you are not getting a context mismatch error.

Comment: added Subscriber class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the Property `Tags` on Subscriber:

```
public ICollection<Subscribers.Models.Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

Entity Framework expects the Tag object to have a foreign-key to Subscriber so it builds a query with it. It looks like to configure the many-to-many relationship needs to change the property to:

```
public ICollection<Subscribers.Models.SubscriberTag> SubscriberTag{ get; set; }
```

[Configuring a Many-to-Many Relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Thanks for the insight Ivan

Comment: You are right for the reason. But the fix should be just changing the `public ICollection<Subscribers.Models.Tag> Tags { get; set; }` to `public ICollection<SubscriberTag> SubscriberTags { get; set; }` as it is in the `Tag` class, since it semm to be a `many-to-many` relationship.

Comment: @IvanStoev That did it (you are correct this is a Many to Many)

Comment: @IvanStoev Of course. I see it now. OP created their own many-to-many joining table in code instead of letting EF take care of it.  Good catch, I was looking at the class properties instead of seeing the naming convention bigger picture.

Comment: @JaredStroeb Actually own join table is the only option you have in EF Core [currently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Ah thanks again.  I have not had the opportunity to use EF core.  I am looking forward to switching over to core in the coming months.